# How would you hide this button in the finally?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise, finally

i wanted to hide the button as soon as the code hits the finally but it won't hide.I wonder how would you guys do it?

here is the html-

```
<body>
<main class="container">
    <div class="countries">
    </div>
    <button class="btn-country">Where am I?</button>
    <div class="images"></div> 
</main> 
</body>
```

and here is the script -

```
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn-country');
const countriesContainer = document.querySelector('.countries');


 const renderError = function (message) {
        countriesContainer.insertAdjacentText('beforeend', message);
        countriesContainer.style.opacity = 1;
    };

    const getCountrydata3 = function (country) {
        fetch(`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/${country}`).then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
    
            renderCountry(data[0]);
    
            //set the neighbour country
            const neighbour = data[0].borders[0];
    
            //the guard clause
            if (!neighbour) return;
    
            //getting the data
    
            return fetch(`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/alpha/${neighbour}`)
        }).then(res => res.json()).then(data => renderCountry(data, 'neighbour')).catch(err => renderError(`Something went wrong! ${err.message}`)).finally(() => {
            console.log('damn button won\'t hide');
btn.style.visibility = hidden;  //<---**Here it is not working**
        })
    };
    
    btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
        getCountrydata3('sfsfsf');
    
    })
```

This button won't hide in the finally. :S

Comment: What is the value of `hidden`?  Don't you mean `'hidden'`?

Comment: My goodness! Thank you for pointing this out.I kept screwing this part.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
btn.style.visibility = "hidden";
```

Or,

```
document.querySelector('.btn-country').style.visibility = "hidden";
```

Or,

```
document.querySelector('.btn-country').style.display ="none";
```

If it does not work try using jquery or any other library that works easily

Comment: Yes.It works fine.I somehow kept screwing up enclosing it inside quotation.Thank You so much! This is liberating! :)